# Viewing results immediately after applying CLI config ForitOS 5.4 200D

Tags: fortigate

Just upgraded to FortiOS 5.4, don't really think that makes a difference here but I don't see my CLI config changes from the GUI. Lets say I edit a firewall policy via CLI then refresh my GUI window, I don't see the change. I wonder if I should also disable automatic write to flash.

Comment: Update: I just performed a reboot and now my edits are view-able from the GUI. I should not have to reboot the appliance to see CLI config changes.

Comment: "_I should not have to reboot the appliance to see CLI config changes._" I suppose you will need to take that up with FortiGate.

Comment: Solved! After the command statement is complete and you are done at that level of config either enter the command "end" or "next". That's what applies the command statement.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up looking for an answer forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! After the command statement is complete and you are done at that level of config either enter the command "end" to go back to the root or "next" which takes you back only one level. Moving out of the current config level will apply the command statements.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.